# On the proliferation of tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

Do we really need *three* different tags for different models of the same device? [iPad 3 - no memory warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783125/ipad-3-no-memory-warning)

[ipad](/questions/tagged/ipad) [ipad2](/questions/tagged/ipad2) [ipad-3](/questions/tagged/ipad-3)

Yes, they're just bits and they don't take up much room, but isn't this what tag synonyms were made for?

Comment: While I agree with you on that, their naming should *at least* be consistent.

Comment: Here's what I'd call a real problem with version tags: [Tags: iOS vs. iOS5 vs. iOS4, etc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109486/tags-ios-vs-ios5-vs-ios4-etc)

Comment: @Bertrand Marron: Completed. Not sure why it wasn't brought up earlier :)

Comment: I'd rather stop the "error codes as tags" crazyness personally: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66352/do-we-really-need-a-tag-for-every-error-code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is such a great difference in hardware between iterations of these devices (the third-generation iPad has a Retina display, dammit) that it would only be sane to have tags for questions that pertain only to each of these models, given potential compatibility issues with apps and such. We do have version tags for all kinds of software anyway, so I don't see any harm in having "version" tags for the hardware/devices that we build software on.

Consistency? Hell yes. I've renamed [ipad2](/questions/tagged/ipad2) to [ipad-2](/questions/tagged/ipad-2) (in the same fashion as [renaming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118722/rename-iphone4-to-iphone-4) [iphone4](/questions/tagged/iphone4) to [iphone-4](/questions/tagged/iphone-4)).

I have no comments about [ipad-3](/questions/tagged/ipad-3); I think we can just leave it at that since the third-generation iPad doesn't have a distinguishing name from the first-generation one, and "iPad 3" has been a popular nickname for it.

Comment: It's [`iPad3` internally](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9640059), following `iPad2`. [tag:ipad-3] is a reasonable name, unlike [certain other proposal](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9638970/revisions).

Comment: Well, yeah, **third**-generation iPad, iPad **3**, makes sense ;)

Comment: Sounds fine. Thanks for the consistency.

Comment: "The new iPad" is the marketing term, just like Windows 6.2 is called "Windows 8".